# SQLite UPDATE poor performance

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, query-optimization, database-performance

The QT application has 1 background thread running where I queue Image objects that need to be updated in the database.

The thread wakes up and dequeues Image objects and calls a DB wrapper that finally executes a simple UPDATE statement on a unique primary key, like this:

```
UPDATE images SET path=... keywords=... caption=... WHERE uuid=...
```

uuid is the primary key. I have also added a UNIQUE INDEX for uuid (among others).

From the tests I've been doing it's taking ~250ms for each update which seems crazy.

Comment: Prep. stamements maybe...?

Comment: What is the data type of UUID?

Comment: Any suggestions of where I should start reading ? Would the performance be much improved?

Comment: UUID is of type TEXT. It's supposed to be a string of around 30 chars long

Comment: Did you measured the time spent by the query by writing it interactively?

Comment: No, I'm testing it from QT by using a timer taking the average over 100 image updates

Comment: One thing you might want to check is, run explain plan and see if the index is being used or not. Is it being suppressed due to data type conversions, etc. ?

Comment: Did you closed and reopened the connection between each update?

Comment: @Renzo, the thread has a database object and it's open all the time, and closed in the destructor.

Comment: @Ramana, will test that...

Comment: Perhaps you could read [this](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) and see if you get some hint...

Comment: @Ramana, it says: "SEARCH TABLE images USING INDEX img_uuid (uuid=?).  Which I suppose is the expected use of the index... right?

Comment: Right, index usage is fine.

Comment: As you write "Update Images" .... How big are they? Try to use a sqlite :memory: db and back it up to the HDD . Sqlite can do such backups as the DB is running and working. https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html

Comment: 250 ms is OK for a single transaction. I guess you're using an automatic transaction for every single statement?

Comment: @CL. Yes, how may I optimize that and use more statements per transaction? I'm running the updates from a thread (and some others from other threads as well).

Comment: @schorsch_76, the images are just text fields like title, caption, keywords, etc. not binary data.

Comment: [QSqlDatabase::transaction()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqldatabase.html#transaction)